# Memory Leak not detected by CRTDBG Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I have a multi threaded server application, written in 'c' that does a lot of network/tcp stuff.  On one customer system the server leaks memory at the rate of about 200mb per day. The server is running windows 2012r2

My internal memory allocation functions don't record the leak.

Using CRTDBG functions to analyze total memory use the leak is also not recorded.

All private dll's we use log all memory allocations, and don't show any memory leaks.

The only other dll's in use are standard default libraries.

It's a 32bit build.

The usual suspects I've eliminated already:
1) thread creation/destruction, if I instead re-use threads the leak remains the same.
2) memory fragmentation causing an apparent leak, I use the non fragmenting malloc, and I've tried pre allocating all the needed memory so no fragmentation will occur, and it still leaks at the same rate.

The leak shows as peak working set, or private working set slowly increases.

I don't see any handle leaks in taskmanager.

So, I'm out of ideas.  Please make crazy suggestions of what else might be using up this amount of memory and NOT recorded by CRTDBG memory logging functions.

Thanks Heaps! (pun intended) :-)

Comment: Get a full process dump and run a heap analysis in WinDBG. 200MB is a big chunk of change to misplace. Peruse the allocated heaps and see if you recognize repetitious data patterns. Regarding leaks of seen in the past that were elusive, leaked views on file mappings was one such rabbit hole. Closing the handle isn't enough, each view has to be unmapped as well or leaks will ensue. Just another thing to check (though, if I remember correctly, such a case doesn't turn up as private bytes; just consumption in the address space until it exhausts (32bit process in my case, thank God).

Comment: You are actually distributing a debug build to the client for testing? _Crt* stuff mostly disappears in release builds (and the license requires that you not distribute the debug libraries). If you do have them run a debug build and don't see anything amiss as said it may well not be a CRT memory leak but some other resource.

Comment: with out the actual code, all we can do is make guesses.  Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Is your application windows-specific or is it possible to compile it for Linux and run there?

Comment: I don't have a minimal complete verifiable example, I have one instance on one customers system (out of a thousand) where the leak occurs and a few hundred thousand lines  of code. I cannot isolate the problem or reproduce it, but it is consistent on the customers system. I have not seen it occur on linux (but it may).  Thanks for the process dump suggestion I'll see what that can do, I don't see how a heap analysis will help since the usage is external to the heap as reported by crtdbg?